# mapM for both keys and values of Data.Map

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a monadic parser instance that transforms Data.Map.Map's:

```
instance (Ord a, FromEDN a, FromEDN b) => FromEDN (M.Map a b) where
    parseEDNv (E.Map m) = mapMmap parseEDNv parseEDN m
    parseEDNv v = typeMismatch "Map" v
```

Data.Map doesn't provide it's own mapM version like Data.Vector does, so i had to write it from scratch:

```
mapMmap :: (Ord a2, Monad m) => (a1 -> m a2) -> (b1 -> m b2) -> M.Map a1 b1 -> m (M.Map a2 b2)
mapMmap kf vf m = do
    let pairsIn = M.assocs m
    pairsOut <- mapM fs pairsIn
    return $! M.fromList pairsOut
    where
        fs (k, v) = do
            newK <- kf k
            newV <- vf v
            return (newK, newV)
```

It works, but very verbose. How to trim into a more succinct INLINEable version without too much black^W monadic magic?

Comment: Have you considered traverseWithKey?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `keys` library which implements

```
mapWithKeyM_ :: (FoldableWithKey t, Monad m) => (Key t -> a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()
```

and related functions for `Data.Map`.

There is also `Data.Traversable.mapM`, but it only maps over values. Mapping over both keys and values is not a `mapM` operation because there is `Ord` constraint.

If you still consider implementing your function yourself, it can be written like this:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Monad

mapMmap :: (Ord a2, Monad m) => 
   (a1 -> m a2) -> (b1 -> m b2) -> M.Map a1 b1 -> m (M.Map a2 b2)
mapMmap kf vf = liftM M.fromList . mapM fs . M.assocs 
    where
    fs (k, v) = liftM2 (,) (kf k) (vf v)
```

Comment: Ah, liftM2, that's how it is used!